# Outer shadow on a rounded image in canvas?

Tags: canvas

If I rounded an image like so:

```
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(25, 25, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.clip();

    context.drawImage("image_here", 0, 0, 50, 50);
```

How would I then add an outer shadow to the rounded image without it being clipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the shadow methods built into canvas

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
let image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556103255-4443dbae8e5a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8cGhvdG9ncmFwaGVyfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80";



context.beginPath();
context.shadowColor = "black";
context.shadowOffsetX = 5;
context.shadowBlur = 8;
context.arc(50, 50, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
context.clip();
context.drawImage(image1, 25, 25, 50, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```